# SYNTAX_ERROR: line 197:33: All COALESCE operands must be the same type: varchar

Tags: sql, presto

I am getting the following error, however I cannot figure out why because both values are string.

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 197:33: All COALESCE operands must be the same type: varchar

This is the line with the issue: coalesce(a.accountid, b.sf_account_id) sf_account_id,

Would you happen to know why?

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT 
        b.*,
        coalesce(a.accountid, b.sf_account_id) sf_account_id,
        coalesce(a.createddate, b.date_invoice) date_invoice
        
    from salesforce.sf_account_history a
    FULL OUTER JOIN add_next_month b 
        on "substr"(a.accountid, 1, ("length"(a.accountid) - 3)) = b.sf_account_id 
            and date_trunc('month',cast( "from_iso8601_timestamp"(a.createddate) as date)) = date_trunc('month',  CAST(date_invoice as date))
```

I tried using cast(column as varchar) and did not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is returned by `typeof(a.accountid)`, `typeof(b.sf_account_id)`, `typeof(a.createddate)` and  `typeof(b.date_invoice)` ?

Comment: they are both varchar. that is why I am a bit confused

Comment: Notice that i have asked for 4 of them ;)

Comment: @CarolineSilva What about the width of the columns? Is one of them max by any chance?

Comment: it was related to the width of the columns. Thanks